# Implementing a recursive function that recursively executes another function

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, html-parsing

Im trying to put together a link analyzer that goes through a websites html code and returns all links that contain the same base url (refer to a webpage of the same site) and im currently have this code put together. (I am a beginner so please bear with the amateur code ^^):

```
import Network.HTTP
import Data.List
import Data.Char

htmlLinks link = do
  content <- simpleHTTP (getRequest link) >>= fmap (take 10000) . getResponseBody
  let string = content
  let tags = splitOn "<" string
  let links = filter (isInfixOf "href") tags
  let filtered = filter (isInfixOf link) links
  let url = map (splitOn "\"") filtered
  let final = map (filter (isInfixOf "http")) url
  let urlString = map (\(h:_) -> h)final
  let result = nub urlString
  --let result = map head $ group $ sort urlString
  return result
```

This function goes through the code and returns me a list of all links with the same base url that I want. Now I want to go through each element of that list and apply the same function to them, so I can get the links on each of those sites aswell, ultimately providing me with all the webpages of a given website structure. So for the recursive function I tried this:

```
linkScanner result = linkRec [] result where
  linkRec acc [] = acc
  linkRec acc (h:t) = linkRec ((htmlLinks h) : acc) t
```

This basically takes the list of links applies the htmlLinks to each element and adds the result of that to my accumulator, which in this case is an empty list. Now my problem is that I can't find a way to combine these 2 functions so that they can be executed with a given URL and provide me with a list of all the links I need. I also have a Type Conflict as htmlLinks is of Type IO[String] and the recursive function needs a [String] which results in an error..

I am looking for some advice on how to solve this problem or some tips that I could use to get to my desired result. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For to add that the fmap (take 10000) for the ResponseBody is only for testing, so that the I can work with smaller chucks of html code. It will be removed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
linkScanner result = linkRec [] result where
linkRec acc [] = return acc
linkRec acc (h:t) = do
   x <- htmlLinks h
   linkRec (x : acc) t
```

(which will return the list in the opposite order) or

```
linkScanner = traverse htmlLinks -- or the analogous with mapM
```

By the way, you should really add type annotations to the top level bindings. It's very hard to think about what's going on otherwise.

Comment: So the code in itself is gonna work with the IO string? Cause that seems to be a problem/error.. The linkScanner function I mean. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @M.O It should.